# Create custom configuration functions in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, configuration, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a function similar to `@@servername` to be created. So, the new `@@mycustomname` will return something I set up and then I can use `@@mycustomname` in my deployed T-SQL Scripts.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I am not certain but I believe the designation of @@(something) is a system reserved variable.  I don't believe you can create these things.  However if you just want a return for metadata or other types that is definitely possible with Scalar functions or custom types.  It all depends on what you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. These are reserved keywords.

What you want to be somewhat equivalent to global variables, which unfortunately does not exists.

The best you can do is declare a function.